# Can I still use my US tourist visa if I depart from a different country to that where I obtained my visa from?

Tags: visas, usa, filipino-citizens

I'm working here now in the Philippines. Worked in Bangkok for a couple of years as a teacher.

I got my US tourist visa in Bangkok when I used to work there, but now I live in the Philippines. I'm a native Filipino. Can I still use my valid visa if I'm gonna fly from Manila and not from Bangkok?

Comment: Is your visa still valid, I assume?

Comment: When did you get it, and when does it expire?

Comment: It's valid for 10 years. Got it last year.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter where you're from. If you've a 10 year tourist/visit visa for US, its probably multiple entry visa & you can visit US anytime you want.

Comment: Even though I got it in a different country and not from my home country? Change of residence doesn't matter? Thanks!

Comment: If you haven't changed your nationality, it wouldn't matter.